# Properties of a random vector $\mathbf{x}$ when $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{H}}]$ is diagonal

Tags: vectors, expectation, independence, covariance, correlation

Let $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{CN} (\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ and let us consider the general case where $\boldsymbol{\mu} \neq \mathbf{0}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is a full-rank, non-diagonal matrix.

What can be said about $\mathbf{x}$ if $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{H}}]$ is a diagonal matrix?

Perhaps the element of $\mathbf{x}$ are somehow independent?

$$ $$

- Some background information in case it's useful. Let $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{CN} (\bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}}, \bar{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}})$: we have $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{y} \mathbf{y}^{\mathrm{H}}] = \bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}} \bar{\boldsymbol{\mu}}^{\mathrm{H}} + \bar{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} = \bar{\mathbf{U}} \bar{\mathbf{D}} \bar{\mathbf{U}}^{\mathrm{H}}$ (after applying the eigenvalue decomposition). Hence, the original vector $\mathbf{x}$ is obtained as $\mathbf{x} = \bar{\mathbf{U}}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\mathbf x = \left[ \begin{array}{c} X \\ Y \end{array} \right]$ where $X=\begin{cases} \phantom{-}1 \\ \phantom{-}0 & \text{each with probability } 1/3, \\ -1 \end{cases}$ and $Y=X^2.$

Then $\operatorname E\left[ \mathbf x \mathbf x^H \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 2/3 & 0  \\ 0 & 2/3 \end{array} \right],$ but the components of $\mathbf x$ are not independent.

The most you will get is that they are uncorrelated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shouldn't the first element of your 2x2 matrix be 2/3 (since it's the expectation of $X^2$)?

Comment: @TheDon : Why? $\displaystyle \left[ \begin{array}{c} X \\  X^2 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \overline X & \overline{X^2} \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array} X\,\overline X & X\, \overline Y \\ X\,\overline Y & Y\,\overline Y \end{array} \right]. \qquad $

Comment: The first elements of the matrix on the right-hand side should be $X \bar{X}$, right?

Comment: @TheDon : Yes. $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: Ok, then $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\rm{H}}] = [2/3 \ 0; 0 \ 2/3]$ in your example. Regardless of this, are you saying that if $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\rm{H}}]$ is diagonal, one can always say that the elements of $\mathbf{x}$ are uncorrelated even if its covariance $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is not diagonal?